# How to filter for timestamps in between two vectors

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse, tibble

I'm a newbie at R and am trying to filter a dataset for rain events plus 2 hours after the rain. I tried and failed to write a function to filter for that, but isn't there an easy way to do it with filter() or something similar?

So far, I have used filter(LRAIN>0) and tried and failed to write an if-condition.

```
foo <- if(Demo$LRAIN > 0) {as.vector(start_date = time) & as.vector(end_date = time + hour(2))}
```

Also, I have tried this:

```
rain_start_time <- Demo$time[Demo$LRAIN > 0]
rain_end_time <- rain_start_time+hours(2)

Demo %>% filter(time > rain_start_time & time < rain_end_time)
```

But it did not result in returning only the rows in between each pair of dates in rain_start_time and rain_end_time.

This is part of my tibble as an example. I would like to keep all the information from the rain events as indicated in the column "LRAIN" (here for example the first rain at 22:40:00) plus the following two hours.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  time                KILOPASCAL LRAIN RAWVOLWATER REFERENCE_KPA
  <dttm>                      <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2019-07-26 22:30:00       -86.1  0          2259.          98.9
2 2019-07-26 22:40:00       -86.2  0.01       2258.          99.0
3 2019-07-26 22:50:00       -86.2  0.01       2258.          98.9
4 2019-07-26 23:00:00       -86.1  0          2259.          98.9
5 2019-07-26 23:10:00       -86.1  0          2258.          98.9
6 2019-07-26 23:20:00       -86.1  0          2259.          98.9
```

I hope somebody can help. Thank you very much already!

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: I think something like: `library(dplyr); library(lubridate); Demo %>% filter(LRAIN <= first(time) + hours(2))`   Will be easier to help & verify if you can share reproducible example, e.g. by including in the text of your question the output of `dput(head(Demo))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the first `time` when `LRAIN > 0` and `filter` all the rows from that time to next 2 hours. In base R, that can be done as

```
rain_start_time <- df$time[which.max(df$LRAIN > 0)]
df[df$time >= rain_start_time & df$time <= rain_start_time + (2 * 60 * 60), ]

#                 time device_sn KILOPASCAL LRAIN RAWVOLWATER REFERENCE_KPA
#2 2019-07-26 22:40:00  z6-01968      -86.2  0.01        2258          99.0
#3 2019-07-26 22:50:00  z6-01968      -86.2  0.01        2258          98.9
#4 2019-07-26 23:00:00  z6-01968      -86.1  0.00        2259          98.9
#5 2019-07-26 23:10:00  z6-01968      -86.1  0.00        2258          98.9
#6 2019-07-26 23:20:00  z6-01968      -86.1  0.00        2259          98.0
```

Or using `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% filter(between(time, rain_start_time, rain_start_time + hours(2)))
```

---

**EDIT**

To include all the rain events, we can do (Using dataframe name as `Demo`) we can remove the first rows till no rain has occurred and then create groups at each rain interval and select rows which occur in the next two hours.

```
Demo %>%
  slice(-seq_len(which.max(LRAIN > 0) - 1)) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(LRAIN > 0)) %>%
  filter(time <= first(time) + hours(2))
```

Or in base R

```
rain_start_time <- Demo$time[Demo$LRAIN > 0]
rain_end_time <- rain_start_time + (2 * 60 * 60)

Demo[unique(unlist(Map(function(x, y) which(Demo$time >= x & Demo$time <= y), 
             rain_start_time, rain_end_time))), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1564151400, 1564152000, 1564152600, 
1564153200, 1564153800, 1564154400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), device_sn = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "z6-01968", class = "factor"), KILOPASCAL = c(-86.1, 
-86.2, -86.2, -86.1, -86.1, -86.1), LRAIN = c(0, 0.01, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0), RAWVOLWATER = c(2259, 2258, 2258, 2259, 2258, 2259), 
REFERENCE_KPA = c(98.9, 99, 98.9, 98.9, 98.9, 98)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like the right way to go. But unfortunately my dataset contains many rain events (the vector rain_start_time contains 600 positions) and every time I try to filter for the vector plus 2 hours, my R-session aborts. Is there a way to make this filter applicable to a larger dataset with many rainevents? Thank you! :)

Comment: @KodakAsis `rain_start_time` should have only one value as we are using `which.max` and not `which`. Anyway, do you want to keep data for next 2 hours for all the rain_events ? So in the data shared 2 hours after `22:40:00` and also 2 hours after `22:50:00` ? Currently, the answer which I have provided keeps data only 2 hours after first rain i.e 2 hours after `22:40:00`.

Comment: @Ronakh Shah True, thank you, but I changed it to only "which" because I need to filter for all the rainevents + 2 hours. So basically I need to filter between a vector of dates + 2 hours for each date. I would like to keep also the 2 hours after adjoining rainfalls, i.e. 22:40 and 22:50, dropping the thereby duplicated rows perhaps in another step.

Comment: @KodakAsis Can you check the updated answer in the **EDIT** part? See if it works for you.